# Interpretation of operators applied to systems with higher symmetry

Tags: symmetry, electrical-resistance, group-theory, representation-theory, crystals

Let me make an example from solid state physics to show what I mean: We can show that for a 2D hexagonal lattice the resistivity is isotropic by noticing that the resistivity tensor is symmetric matrix and describes an ellipse. The hexagonal lattice however has a higher symmetry which implies that we must use the trivial representation for the resistivity (i.e. the identity) which makes the resistivity isotropic for the hexagonal lattice.

My question is now the following: What is the relationship between the symmetries of the operator and the system we apply it to (in this case the hexagon) mathematically? What role does the representation play in this?